# XSLT Formatting output 90% Completed

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to process some XML to reform it so that this input, however the issue i am getting can be illustrated better below:

INPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
 <doc:ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response xmlns:doc="urn:sapcom:document:sap:rfc:functions">
    <MESSAGE>Success</MESSAGE>
    <STATUS>0</STATUS>
     <COLLECTION>
         <item>
            <COLLECTION>A1</COLLECTION>
            <SEASON>S09</SEASON>
            <TEXT>Spring Market A1</TEXT>
        </item>
         <item>
            <COLLECTION>A1</COLLECTION>
            <SEASON>S10</SEASON>
            <TEXT>Spring Market A1</TEXT>
        </item>
     </COLLECTION>
</doc:ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response>
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
 <doc:ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response xmlns:doc="urn:sapcom:document:sap:rfc:functions">
    <MESSAGE>Success</MESSAGE>
    <STATUS>0</STATUS>
     <COLLECTION>
         <item>
            <COLLECTION>A1</COLLECTION>
            <SEASON>S09,S10</SEASON>
            <TEXT>Spring Market A1</TEXT>
        </item>
     </COLLECTION>
</doc:ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response>
```

XSLT being used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="k" match="item" use="COLLECTION"/>

    <xsl:template match="/ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response">
        <xsl:copy>
            <COLLECTIONS>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="COLLECTION/item[generate-id() = 
                    generate-id(key('k', COLLECTION))]"/>
            </COLLECTIONS>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="COLLECTION/item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="COLLECTION"/>
            <SEASON>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('k', COLLECTION)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="SEASON"/>

                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </SEASON>
            <xsl:copy-of select="TEXT"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

CURRENT INCORRECT OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response xmlns=""><?xml version="1.0"?>
    Success0<item xmlns:doc="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions"><COLLECTION>A1</COLLECTION><SEASON>S09,S10,S12</SEASON><TEXT>Spring Market A1</TEXT></item>
  </ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="k" match="item" use="COLLECTION"/>

    <xsl:template match="item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', COLLECTION))]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="COLLECTION"/>
            <SEASON>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('k', COLLECTION)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="SEASON"/>

                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </SEASON>
            <xsl:copy-of select="TEXT"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML:

```
<doc:ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response xmlns:doc="urn:sapcom:document:sap:rfc:functions">
    <MESSAGE>Success</MESSAGE>
    <STATUS>0</STATUS>
    <COLLECTION>
        <item>
            <COLLECTION>A1</COLLECTION>
            <SEASON>S09</SEASON>
            <TEXT>Spring Market A1</TEXT>
        </item>
        <item>
            <COLLECTION>A1</COLLECTION>
            <SEASON>S10</SEASON>
            <TEXT>Spring Market A1</TEXT>
        </item>
    </COLLECTION>
</doc:ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response>
```

it produces wanted correct result:

```
<doc:ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response xmlns:doc="urn:sapcom:document:sap:rfc:functions">
  <MESSAGE>Success</MESSAGE>
  <STATUS>0</STATUS>
  <COLLECTION>
    <item>
      <COLLECTION>A1</COLLECTION>
      <SEASON>S09,S10</SEASON>
      <TEXT>Spring Market A1</TEXT>
    </item>
  </COLLECTION>
</doc:ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response>
```

Comment: Is there a way of also removing this `xmlns:doc="urn:sapcom:document:sap:rfc:functions"`??

Comment: @Keevil, Remove from output XML?

Comment: not only am i getting it in `<doc:ZINITIALIZE_FILTERS.Response xmlns:doc="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">` im also getting it in `<SEASON xmlns:doc="urn:sapcom:document:sap:rfc:functions">S09,S10,</SEASON>`

Comment: @Keevil, It's strange behavior. In MSXML I got result provided above.

Comment: The reason i think i am having this issue is because i am using an XSLT Transformation inside of a tool called Cast Iron, and it sometimes does some funny things to tags. However it is not an issue and still performs as i desired, so thank you very much!